# regular expression - matching literal that contains non-empty quotes

Tags: regex

In a JSON file i have many keys, with the same name, that can have a string value.

I want to find these keys, when they have value and not empty.
example:

```
{
  x: {
    "key": ""
  }
  y: {
    "key": "string" // match this
  }  
}
```

I've tried this, and failed.

```
\"key\":\"*\"
```

**edit**

---

I must work with it as a string.
sometimes (like now) i'm using the notepad++'s regex search tool

Comment: As you already realized, it's JSON. Why don't you parse it and check the keys later instead of doing regex?

Comment: which json dependency are you using ?

Comment: check the `edit` please

Answer (score 1):

If to use Perl, Notepad++, Java or Groovy regular expressions, then `*` (like in your example) matches  any number of chars (zero including) and + matches non empty sequence of at least one character. The character preceding `+` or `*`.

If the value consists of word characters only, the simplest seems to use something like `\"w+\"` instead of your current `\"w*\"` that would match also two subsequent quotes. I would not expect special characters or spaces inside that is called a "key" in your code.